# Why doesn't the program throw segfault error on editing fixed string?

Tags: segmentation-fault, structure, unions

I am newbie to Unions. In the following code, according to my understanding, we are editing a fixed string literal "GeeksQuiz" by trying to replace with 'S' inplace of G. Shouldn't it throw some segfault error. If not then why isn't the answer "SeeksQuiz" and is "GeeksQuiz" ?

```
# include <iostream> 
# include <string.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
struct Test 
{ 
  char str[20]; 
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
  struct Test st1, st2; 
  strcpy(st1.str, "GeeksQuiz"); 
  st2 = st1; 
  st1.str[0] = 'S'; 
  cout << st2.str; 
  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me breakdown what is happening here line by line:

1. `Struct Test st1, st2;`
   creates two local struct Tests. These are not pointers / references, but the structs themselves.
   if you try to print out the structs, they will have random characters since str is not initialized.
2. `strcpy(st1.str, "GeeksQuiz");`
   Copies the string literal GeeksQuiz to st1.str, so st1.str should have GeeksQuiz with null terminating character.
3. `st2 = st1;`
   We set st1 to be equal to st2. Both are not pointers or references, (flat objects) so its like

   ```
   int a = 5;
   int b = 6;
   a = b; // a = 6
   a = 7; // a = 7, b is still 6
   ```

So `st2.str` = GeeksQuiz, `st1.str` = GeeksQuiz, but they (st1, st2) both are separate entities.

4. `st1.str[0] = 'S';`
   st1.str = SeeksQuiz, st2.str = GeeksQuiz.
5. `cout << st2.str;`
   st2.str = GeeksQuiz, which is what gets outputted.

We are nowhere trying to change the actual literal itself, anytime we use literals to initialize something, it is copied to that variable. I hope all this clarifies your question.

If `st1` and `st2` were pointers to structs, then setting `st1 = st2` both will point to the same place in memory, so changing something through `*st1` will be reflected in `*st2` as well, but thats not the case here.